# ColorButton gives 12 digits hex string instead of 6

Tags: pygtk

I've inserted a gtk.ColorButton() but when I retrieve the value (get_color) I obtain a 12 digits hex string (for certain colors).
The problem is that I need it to give me only 6 digits.

Here's a snippet :

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require("2.0")

import gtk

class TestColorButton(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.win = gtk.Window()
        self.colorbutton = gtk.ColorButton()
        container = gtk.VBox()
        Button = gtk.Button("Get color")
        Button.connect("released", self.get_selected_color)
        container.pack_start(self.colorbutton)
        container.pack_start(Button)
        self.win.add(container)
        self.win.show_all()

    def get_selected_color(self, widget):
        print self.colorbutton.get_color()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestColorButton()
    gtk.main()
```

I don't know if the only solution would be to try to convert the 12 digits hex string to a 6 digits one (even though I would be losing information). Since nothing in python can use a 12 digits color I'm seriously wondering what was the use of this...

The funny part is that in the window that pops up I can see a 6 digits hex string. Maybe if I can get_childs that window until I find it... but it seems complicated for a simple matter...

Comment: Actually it should return an object gtk.gdk.Color 
http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkcolor.html

and not a string, from the returned object you can read the values as stated in the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal was to obtain a 6 digit hex string for a color I picked. One temporary solution was to take the first two digits of each four digit color (#rrrrggggbbbb gives #rrggbb).
What I choosed was 
to convert each four digit color into 16 bits integer (0000-FFFF to 0-65535)
rescale it to 8 bits (0-65535 to 0-255)
convert it back to hex string (which gives now two characters instead of four)

I don't think it is really clever but at least it gives me approximatively the color I wanted...

The snippet updated:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require("2.0")

import gtk

class TestColorButton(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.win = gtk.Window()
        self.colorbutton = gtk.ColorButton()
        container = gtk.VBox()
        Button = gtk.Button("Get color")
        Button.connect("released", self.get_selected_color)
        container.pack_start(self.colorbutton)
        container.pack_start(Button)
        self.win.add(container)
        self.win.show_all()

    def get_selected_color(self, widget):
        a = self.colorbutton.get_color()
        print a
        self.gdk_to_hex(a)

    def gdk_to_hex(self, gdk_color):
        colors = gdk_color.to_string()
        a =  "#"+"".join([self.fourtotwohexdigit(i) for i in (colors[1:5], colors[5:9], colors[9:13])])
        print a

    def fourtotwohexdigit(self, hexa):
        return hex(int(int(hexa,16)*255/65535))[2:]     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestColorButton()
    gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

here's a little func that uses the to_floats function of gdk.color to get the rgb tripple in [0..1] range and then converts it to [0..255] suitable for the 2 digit hex.

```
def gdk_to_hex(gdk_color):
    colors = gdk_color.to_floats()
    return "#" + "".join(["%02x" % (color * 255) for color in colors])
```

Comment: the gtk.gdk.color object I have don't have any to_floats() method. But I updated the code I had with my temporary correction using part of your code.

Comment: http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/api/Gdk_3.0/structs/Color.html?highlight=to_floats#Gdk.Color.to_floats - doesn't mention the version, so could have been introduced in gtk3

Answer (score -1):

When you get the object gtk.gdk.Color from

```
color = self.colorbutton.get_color()
```

you can get the string representation with

```
color.to_string()
```

The 12 digit #fcfce9e94f4f string contains the hex form 4 digit of each color, in this case red=64764, green=59881, blue=20303

```
red=64764 -> fcfc
green=59881 -> e9e9
blue=20303 -> 4f4f
```

you can also print individual colors from the gtk.gdk.Color like

```
color.red
color.green
color.blue
```

or if you prefer in the decimal value in range 0.0 - 1.0

```
color.red_float
color.green_float
color.blue_float
```